# How to keep axios get request running till we get specific result in response

Tags: api, express, async-await, axios, promise

My axios get call takes few seconds to have result as 'succeeded' as below result

```
{
    "status": "succeeded",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-12-01T02:42:04Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-12-01T02:42:06Z",
    "analyzeResult": {
        "version": "3.2.0",
        "modelVersion": "2022-04-30",
        "readResults": [
            {
                "page": 1,
                "angle": 12.8499,
                "width": 1
```

However sometimes I get below response with status running with no analyzeResult.

```
{
    "status": "running",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-12-01T02:42:04Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-12-01T02:42:06Z",
```

What should be the way to have api call running till we get status as succeeded.

I tried below code with async await and also then catch

```
const result=  await axios.get(url,headers)
console.log(result.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with async/await, If I understand this correctly Backend is sending the response with the status key, and FE will start executing once the response is received. It does not care about status.

**Solution:**

1. Ask the backend to wait until the operation gets completed and then send the response.
2. Send the response with the status key as soon as the operation starts, and expose another API for checking the status of the operation. This is useful when operations take more time.